# Cannot resolve a reference component schema defined in requestBody in yaml file

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

When I'm trying to resolve reference in my YAML file. The references are not fully resolved and left as $ref in the request body. Could you please let me know how can it be fixed?

content of the yaml file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: refComponent
  description: refComponent
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: 'https'
paths:
  /pets:
    post:
      summary: Creates a new user.
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      required:
        - userName
      properties:
        userName:
          type: string
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
```

Here is the parser option I used

```
ParseOptions parseOptions = new ParseOptions();
parseOptions.setResolve(true);
parseOptions.setResolveFully(true);
parseOptions.setFlatten(true);
OpenAPI api = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read(definitionURI, null, parseOptions);
```

The received output from OpenAPI3Parser

```
class OpenAPI {
    openapi: 3.0.0
    info: class Info {
        title: refComponent
        description: refComponent
        termsOfService: null
        contact: null
        license: null
        version: 1.0.0
    }
    externalDocs: null
    servers: [class Server {
        url: https
        description: null
        variables: null
    }]
    security: null
    tags: null
    paths: class Paths {
        {/pets=class PathItem {
            summary: null
            description: null
            get: null
            put: null
            post: class Operation {
                tags: null
                summary: Creates a new user.
                description: null
                externalDocs: null
                operationId: null
                parameters: null
                requestBody: class RequestBody {
                    description: null
                    content: class Content {
                        {application/json=class MediaType {
                            schema: class Schema {
                                type: null
                                format: null
                                $ref: #/components/schemas/body
                                description: null
                                title: null
                                multipleOf: null
                                maximum: null
                                exclusiveMaximum: null
                                minimum: null
                                exclusiveMinimum: null
                                maxLength: null
                                minLength: null
                                pattern: null
                                maxItems: null
                                minItems: null
                                uniqueItems: null
                                maxProperties: null
                                minProperties: null
                                required: null
                                not: null
                                properties: null
                                additionalProperties: null
                                nullable: null
                                readOnly: null
                                writeOnly: null
                                example: null
                                externalDocs: null
                                deprecated: null
                                discriminator: null
                                xml: null
                            }
                            examples: null
                            example: null
                            encoding: null
                        }}
                    }
                    required: null
                }
                responses: class ApiResponses {
                    {200=class ApiResponse {
                        description: OK
                        headers: null
                        content: null
                        links: null
                        extensions: null
                        $ref: null
                    }}
                    extensions: null
                }
                callbacks: null
                deprecated: null
                security: null
                servers: null
            }
            delete: null
            options: null
            head: null
            patch: null
            trace: null
            servers: null
            parameters: null
            $ref: null
        }}
    }
    components: class Components {
        schemas: {User=class ObjectSchema {
            class Schema {
                type: object
                format: null
                $ref: null
                description: null
                title: null
                multipleOf: null
                maximum: null
                exclusiveMaximum: null
                minimum: null
                exclusiveMinimum: null
                maxLength: null
                minLength: null
                pattern: null
                maxItems: null
                minItems: null
                uniqueItems: null
                maxProperties: null
                minProperties: null
                required: [userName]
                not: null
                properties: {userName=class StringSchema {
                    class Schema {
                        type: string
                        format: null
                        $ref: null
                        description: null
                        title: null
                        multipleOf: null
                        maximum: null
                        exclusiveMaximum: null
                        minimum: null
                        exclusiveMinimum: null
                        maxLength: null
                        minLength: null
                        pattern: null
                        maxItems: null
                        minItems: null
                        uniqueItems: null
                        maxProperties: null
                        minProperties: null
                        required: null
                        not: null
                        properties: null
                        additionalProperties: null
                        nullable: null
                        readOnly: null
                        writeOnly: null
                        example: null
                        externalDocs: null
                        deprecated: null
                        discriminator: null
                        xml: null
                    }
                }, firstName=class StringSchema {
                    class Schema {
                        type: string
                        format: null
                        $ref: null
                        description: null
                        title: null
                        multipleOf: null
                        maximum: null
                        exclusiveMaximum: null
                        minimum: null
                        exclusiveMinimum: null
                        maxLength: null
                        minLength: null
                        pattern: null
                        maxItems: null
                        minItems: null
                        uniqueItems: null
                        maxProperties: null
                        minProperties: null
                        required: null
                        not: null
                        properties: null
                        additionalProperties: null
                        nullable: null
                        readOnly: null
                        writeOnly: null
                        example: null
                        externalDocs: null
                        deprecated: null
                        discriminator: null
                        xml: null
                    }
                }, lastName=class StringSchema {
                    class Schema {
                        type: string
                        format: null
                        $ref: null
                        description: null
                        title: null
                        multipleOf: null
                        maximum: null
                        exclusiveMaximum: null
                        minimum: null
                        exclusiveMinimum: null
                        maxLength: null
                        minLength: null
                        pattern: null
                        maxItems: null
                        minItems: null
                        uniqueItems: null
                        maxProperties: null
                        minProperties: null
                        required: null
                        not: null
                        properties: null
                        additionalProperties: null
                        nullable: null
                        readOnly: null
                        writeOnly: null
                        example: null
                        externalDocs: null
                        deprecated: null
                        discriminator: null
                        xml: null
                    }
                }}
                additionalProperties: null
                nullable: null
                readOnly: null
                writeOnly: null
                example: null
                externalDocs: null
                deprecated: null
                discriminator: null
                xml: null
            }
        }, body=class ObjectSchema {
            class Schema {
                type: object
                format: null
                $ref: null
                description: null
                title: null
                multipleOf: null
                maximum: null
                exclusiveMaximum: null
                minimum: null
                exclusiveMinimum: null
                maxLength: null
                minLength: null
                pattern: null
                maxItems: null
                minItems: null
                uniqueItems: null
                maxProperties: null
                minProperties: null
                required: [userName]
                not: null
                properties: {userName=class StringSchema {
                    class Schema {
                        type: string
                        format: null
                        $ref: null
                        description: null
                        title: null
                        multipleOf: null
                        maximum: null
                        exclusiveMaximum: null
                        minimum: null
                        exclusiveMinimum: null
                        maxLength: null
                        minLength: null
                        pattern: null
                        maxItems: null
                        minItems: null
                        uniqueItems: null
                        maxProperties: null
                        minProperties: null
                        required: null
                        not: null
                        properties: null
                        additionalProperties: null
                        nullable: null
                        readOnly: null
                        writeOnly: null
                        example: null
                        externalDocs: null
                        deprecated: null
                        discriminator: null
                        xml: null
                    }
                }, firstName=class StringSchema {
                    class Schema {
                        type: string
                        format: null
                        $ref: null
                        description: null
                        title: null
                        multipleOf: null
                        maximum: null
                        exclusiveMaximum: null
                        minimum: null
                        exclusiveMinimum: null
                        maxLength: null
                        minLength: null
                        pattern: null
                        maxItems: null
                        minItems: null
                        uniqueItems: null
                        maxProperties: null
                        minProperties: null
                        required: null
                        not: null
                        properties: null
                        additionalProperties: null
                        nullable: null
                        readOnly: null
                        writeOnly: null
                        example: null
                        externalDocs: null
                        deprecated: null
                        discriminator: null
                        xml: null
                    }
                }, lastName=class StringSchema {
                    class Schema {
                        type: string
                        format: null
                        $ref: null
                        description: null
                        title: null
                        multipleOf: null
                        maximum: null
                        exclusiveMaximum: null
                        minimum: null
                        exclusiveMinimum: null
                        maxLength: null
                        minLength: null
                        pattern: null
                        maxItems: null
                        minItems: null
                        uniqueItems: null
                        maxProperties: null
                        minProperties: null
                        required: null
                        not: null
                        properties: null
                        additionalProperties: null
                        nullable: null
                        readOnly: null
                        writeOnly: null
                        example: null
                        externalDocs: null
                        deprecated: null
                        discriminator: null
                        xml: null
                    }
                }}
                additionalProperties: null
                nullable: null
                readOnly: null
                writeOnly: null
                example: null
                externalDocs: null
                deprecated: null
                discriminator: null
                xml: null
            }
        }}
        responses: null
        parameters: null
        examples: null
        requestBodies: null
        headers: null
        securitySchemes: null
        links: null
        callbacks: null
    }
}
```

Could you please let me know why this **$ref: #/components/schemas/body** is not be resolved in the OpenAPIV3Parser()?

Answer (score 1):

It was resolved by disabling

```
parseOptions.setFlatten(true);
```